# Is it a good practice to include empty/white space checks in RegEx?

Tags: c#, regular-expressions

The goal of the RegEx is to match exactly 6 characters, but in addition it should match empty strings or white space (e.g: `^$|\s|^(\w){6}$`). Is it good practice check for empty string/white space in a RegEx expression, or to perform this check in the higher level code, such as `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`? There seems to be a code smell to doing it in the RegEx, but I may be imagining things.

Thanks.

Comment: If you anticipate having to use one part as a regex, I'd put all the items in a single regex that validates all the forms at once. It just has to be refactored `^(?:\s*|\w{6})$`. There is software that can refactor this for you. See https://justpaste.it/1y9w8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing *interspersed* whitespace and still demanding exactly six characters's worth of input is expensive and should definitely be done outside a regex, e.g. via a replace() before the match is applied.

Allowing whitespace at the start or end is reasonably efficient even within a regular expression, but even so it's probably better just to call trim() (or whatever that's called in C#) first. At the very least, it will make the core purpose of the validation clearer - regexes are hard to understand as it is, no need to burden it with two slightly different purposes.

Comment: Thanks. This perspective made a lot of sense to me, "At the very least, it will make the core purpose of the validation clearer"